# Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications have no sound on some devices

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification to my devices, and it works well. Except on one of the devices there is no sound when receiving the notification.

I use this function to get FCM to send a notification to the device:

```
function sendNotification(){
    const toSend ={
        notification:
        {
            title:"Video Call!",
            body:"Video call!",
            click_action: "....",
            sound: "default",
            vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]
        },
        to:othermailandtoken[1]
        };
        
        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);
        
        
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', true);
        xhr.onload = function(){
        console.log("google response: ",this.responseText);
        }
        
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","key=......);
    xhr.send(jsonString);
}
```

I tried it on Huawei P20 Pro, and it works. The device plays the default, very basic sound when receiving this notification.
However, when I try it on a Xiaomi mi 9se, there is no sound.

What could be the reason for my problem? That device has no default sound? Should I somehow add my own sound into the program?

Comment: Did you check your system sound notifications for your app? Some devices disable this by default.

Comment: Yes, it was enabled.

Comment: Besides "sound" have you set the "channel_id" tag (needed for API level 26+)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidnotification

Comment: I haven't. Is it also needed if the project is in javascript? (PWA)